# Combination Filters in AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I see this documentation on AG-Grid's site about filters https://blog.ag-grid.com/advanced-filtering-in-ag-grid-using-or-filtering-conditions/#custom-filter-panel.

I am trying to see if combination filters are possible on AG-Grid.

I haven't tried anything yet as I need to know how to do this on AG-Grid but a combination filter is what I am trying to achieve.

An example of what I am calling a combination filter is below:

Country = United States **AND** Year > 2005
**OR**
Country = Australia **AND** Year < 2004